# How to transform one aggregate to another in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

Where I work we've got wallets with transactions (i.e. every transaction belongs to a single wallet). Currently we're working on an addition of transfers between wallets. As a part of this, a new `Transfer` concept has been added to the ubiquitous language dictionary.

One functional requirement is to give users the option to change a transaction to a transfer. Because a regular transaction and a transfer have got different validation rules (such as who can edit the aggregate, which attributes are editable,...) and because transfers are a different concept from a transaction, I have created a separate aggregate to represent a transfer.

Now I am however facing a problem how to store the data. I have a command handler with a call to a `Transaction.changeToTransfer` returning a `Transfer` instance. I am fine with this approach, but where I got stuck was the persistence.

Upon changing a transaction to a transfer, the original regular transaction should become a transfer and I am not sure where exactly this transformation is supposed to happen.

One of the ideas that came into my mind was not to have a transfer concept as a separate aggregate at all and represent the transfer relationship as internal values of a regular transaction, however I don't really like the idea of a transfer having access to methods of a regular transaction which the transfer should not have at all, hence why I chose the path of having a separate aggregate.

An example of a behaviour difference is: a user can edit pretty much any attribute on a regular transaction, on the transfer only a memo field may be edited and only by the current "owner" of the transfer. Seems like introducing checks to all other update methods involving `if(isTransfer()) { ... throw ... }` seems wrong.

Which modelling approach should I take tackling this concept and transforming one aggregate into another?

Comment: A transfer is a *specific type* of transaction.

Comment: I was going to say what what Robert said, but in the form of a question.  It sounds like you are taking a generic transaction and promoting it to the specialised "transfer" transaction.  Is this correct?

Comment: What would happen if somehow, a user would want to perform an action on a `transaction` that was `transformed` into a `transfer`? I try to see if there are different concepts or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree that a transfer really is a transaction going to or from somewhere out of/into a specific wallet, however in this current scenario, those are considered to be different types. Kind of as if a transfer was superior to a transaction and transaction was merely a representation of the transfer while transfer itself had a special behaviour.

Comment: @MetaFight, exactly that.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu, depends on the operation. E.g., as mentioned in the question, updating memo of both transaction and or transfer is possible, however that's about where it ends for a transfer. A transaction, however, may have updated other attributes such as amount, date when a transaction has been made,... On top of that, a transfer can be only changed by its current owner, transaction may be changed by one having access to it (i.e. anyone having access to the wallet in which the transaction is).

Comment: Please read [What is the X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937) and respond.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you for the effort. The question I am also hoping to have answered is, can I create a transfer aggregate from the transaction aggregate by reusing the original transaction's id as the transfer id and an implementation of a repository would decide whether a transfer is supposed to be created from fresh or instead an existing regular transaction should be changed to a transfer?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the *other* transaction methods that don't pertain to transfers?

Comment: Sure, @MetaFight. e.g. `changeAmount(newAmount: Number, currency: Currency)` - changes the amount of a regular transaction to a new one, `changeDate(newDate: Date)` - changes the date of a transaction, `addReminder(reminder: Reminder)` - adds information about reminding about a future transaction. None of those methods are supposed to be available on transfer, because changing those things on a transfer has been created is forbidden. As I have said, I could disable those methods using exceptions (if I chose inheritance), but I don't really like that.

Comment: Hrm.  It sounds like the concept of **recurrence** is intertwined with the concept of **transaction**.  Would it make sense to separate the two?

Comment: I am not against any separation @MetaFight, I welcome any sensible approach. Still, it's not only the recurrence, it's the date and amount settings as well. Based on your comment I understood those would require separation as well? If so, could you, please, provide an example of such design? I am completely lost here. :D

Comment: I'm short on time atm, and in order to give you a meaningful answer (meaningful to you and future readers) you would need to update your question... but the general idea is that a `StandingOrder` would model a recurrence of `Transactions`.  It would have a list a past `Transaction`s and enough information to calculate *projected* `Transactions`.  A `Transaction` is merely an amount, currency, source, and destination.  A `StandingOrderTransaction` would derive from `Transaction` and have an additional reference to its parent `StandingOrder`.  A `Transfer` would be what we've already discussed.

Comment: Recurrence aside, what is the role and where should I place the other methods, such as `changeAmount`? Based on your suggestion, I could have a transaction aggregate defining common attributes and methods for a transfer and a regular transaction and then to have two children, `RegularTransaction` and `TransferTransaction`, each modelling their respective behaviour. Does that make sense?

Comment: What does `changeAmount` do?  I'm assuming it changes the amount in the upcoming transaction of a `StandingOrder`.  I assume this because in most banking contexts it makes sense for `Transactions` to be immutable.  They are records of an event and thus can't be changed.
But there's really too much to cover here in this Q&A format.  `Transfer` could derive from `Transaction` or it could just be related to it.  It's hard to tell without you describing the Domain in detail.

Comment: In our system the transactions are actually mutable, @MetaFight, so changing an amount of a transaction updates it. The system I am working on allows users to manually track their finances, so the rules about editing are not as strings as if I was working e.g. on a bank system.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like inheritance in your Domain Model.

`Transfer` *derives* from `Transaction` because it is a specific kind of `Transaction` with potentially more information and behaviour.

The new question now is:

**How do I model inheritance in my persistence?**

There are several ways of doing this, but it will depend on the kind of database you're using.

IIRC, Entity Framework used to accomplish this with Relational Databases by having one table for each type, and derived type tables shared primary keys with the base type tables.

So, in your example, you would have a `Transaction` table and a `Transfer` table, and each `Transfer` record would have a corresponding `Transaction` record with a matching primary key.

Comment: All true.  The real question is, is that what the OP really needs?

Comment: You may be on to something.  [This comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369641/how-to-transform-one-aggregate-to-another-in-ddd/369653#comment809888_369641) makes it sounds like there may be larger domain modelling issues that need to be addressed first.

Comment: I don't think inheritance solves this problem. By making a transfer a child of a transaction, a transfer would inherit the transaction's methods as well, which, as pointed out in the original post, based on the business requirements are not supposed to be even available. I don't like the idea of polluting the public API of the transfer class with unusable, i.e. those to be disabled, transaction methods just by inheriting a transaction.

Comment: which is why I said there may be a larger modelling problem.  Those methods that are not relevant to a `Transfer` should maybe reside on another derivation of `Transaction`.

Comment: Could you perhaps in your answer, please, expand on what you mean by another derivation? A simple example would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand what you mean by the derivation concept.